# How does a vorpal weapon interact with a ranger's quarry?

Tags: dnd-4e

Vorpal weapon reads:

> Whenever you roll the maximum result on any damage die for this weapon, roll that die again and add the additional result to the damage total. If a rerull results in another maximum damage result, roll it again and keep adding.

Hunter's Quarry reads:

> Once per round, when you hit your quarry with an attack, the attack deals extra damage based on your level.
>
> [...]
>
> 1st-10th: +1d6
> 11th-20th: +2d6
> 21st-30th: +3d6

If I attack my quarry with a vorpal weapon, does the vorpal effect (rerolling dice that roll their maximum) apply to the extra damage dice from Hunter's Quarry?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes**, reroll all dice used that roll their maximum.  Note that the normal damage dice are not considered to be rolled when you critical, they just score their maximum and do not get rerolled.

WoTC Customer service has answered this several times.  The most complete answer is [here](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/19685882/Consolidated_Customer_Service_Answers?post_id=334793290#334793290).